# How to add cursor and activate my editText?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext, cursor

Actually I am creating a **custom** `EditText` in my android application.
What I have done is that I have created a class called `CustomEditText`, in which I am drawing my EditText. Its code as follows:

```
public class CustomEditText extends View {

String mText;
Context mContext;
Paint paint = new Paint();

public CustomEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE); // You could setup the background etc here
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    drawTextOnCanvas(canvas, mText);
}

private void drawTextOnCanvas(final Canvas canvas, String mText) {
    canvas.drawPaint(paint);

    final EditText editText = new EditText(mContext);
    editText.setTextColor(BLACK);
    editText.setEnabled(true);

    editText.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    editText.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(canvas.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), 50);

    editText.layout(0, 0, editText.getMeasuredWidth(), editText.getMeasuredHeight());

    canvas.drawBitmap(editText.getDrawingCache(), 0, 0, paint);
    editText.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
}
```

and this class is being called in the `MainActivity` using the following code:

```
    CustomEditText editText = new CustomEditText(this);
    setContentView(editText);
```

What should I be doing next to add a **cursor** and make this **CustomEditText** act like normal **editText**( which means that it should be able to **accept**, **select** and **clear** input text ).

Comment: You mean to show the keyboard?

Comment: merely showing keyboard is easy, it can be done via manifest.
But what I want is to implement it like a normal edittext

Comment: I just checked your checked, what is the mText you are passing to `drawTextOnCanvas ` and where are you using it?

Comment: In your github code you are only adding `height`, not `width`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `drawTextOnCanvas()` is working properly, just making your `CustomEditText` extend `EditText` should work. (instead of `view`)

If I understand your comment correctly, you just have to do this :

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText {

   Context mContext;
   Paint paint;
   EditText editText;


   @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
   public CustomEditText(Context context) {
      super(context);
      paint = new Paint();
      editText = new EditText(context);
      mContext = context;
      paint.setColor(Color.GREEN); 
      paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     canvas.drawPaint(paint);
     super.onDraw(canvas);
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with your `drawTextOnCanvas()`, i just copied your code and commented  `drawTextOnCanvas(canvas, mText);` it works fine(because of `super.ondraw()`).

Comment: so what should I be doing .. remove the input parameters

Comment: So your class is customized only in terms `color` and `style` right? Other than that you want it to act it like a normal `Edittext` right?

Comment: Hey @karthik I removed `String mText` from it, and now its working but whatever I am typing is not being shown. Its just blank.....

Comment: Yes I saw that, what is the API version you are targeting?

Comment: My API version is 19 and above

Comment: Then check my answer, that will work. `paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
` only works for after 17, that's why I was asking. Just use the class in my answer.

Comment: its working thanks for the help, but just one last thing ... how to adjust its size.... like for the width n height of editText

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82773/discussion-between-karthik-and-aditya-prasun).

Comment: You can just use `editext.setWidth()` and `editext.setWidth()` (Set it in constructor if you don't have to change it again)

Comment: have already tried it at both locations but still of no help..... in the constructor and mainActivity when I am calling it

Comment: You must be doing something wrong, can you show your code?